# Angular JS and AJAX posting data doesn't work first click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I focus on Angular JS and I try to posting data with AJAX in ANGULARJS it's working but not first time.

In my html button has ng-click="check()"

This is my app.js code.

```
    var app=angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("control",function($scope){

    $scope.check=function (){
    var mesaj = {
        content: $scope.content,
        flag:"message"
    }
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'send.php',
        data: {query: mesaj},
        success: function (result)
        {
            $scope.result=result;
        }
    });
    }
});
```

and my send.php is taking data(content) after that echo $content

I have double click to button for working AJAX but I want to work at first time

Comment: please use `$http` service instead of jquery

Comment: have you checked the console log? Some variable is undeclared i think

Comment: I checked console log but there isn't anything @peter

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using the `http` service,

you need to tell angular that variables were modified.

by doing `$scope.$apply()` after your success.

```
var app=angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("control",function($scope){

    $scope.check=function (){
    var mesaj = {
        content: $scope.content,
        flag:"message"
    }
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'send.php',
        data: {query: mesaj},
        success: function (result)
        {
            $scope.result=result;
            $scope.$apply()
        }
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why ?. Sure i agree i would just use $http, but it works just fine.

Comment: Not really. It just forces a new digest. Angular1 is just not really great performance wise, doesn't do much more than that.

Comment: please see this http://www.codingeek.com/angularjs/angular-js-apply-timeout-digest-evalasync/

Comment: As i said, it does force a new digest. No saying its not costly, but the OP was asking a solution with $.ajax, that's what i gave. The cost $apply() is usually negligible unless working with large datasets, like a list of 10k+ items.

Comment: can you send sample code with $http .İ try but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Inject $http and call a post, it follows better convention when using angular for posting data:

```
 function sendMesaj() {

         $http.post('send.php', mesaj)
            .then(function(result){

                $scope.result=result;

            }, handleError);

        function handleError(response){
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://portnetsis.xyz/deneme.html  I try it but it doesn't work i take these error
-->
angular.js:14362 ReferenceError: handleError is not defined
    at b.$scope.check (app.js:12)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15197), <anonymous>:4:135)
    at e (angular.js:26808)
    at b.$eval (angular.js:18017)
    at b.$apply (angular.js:18117)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:26813)
    at dg (angular.js:3617)
    at HTMLInputElement.d (angular.js:3605)

Comment: handleError was an example function you could use to catch exceptions... Your code needs to be heavily refactored ... but based on the above error make sure you call the post somehow inside the defined scope function